# Horizontal ListView in ScrollablePositionedList throwing 'notification.metrics.axis == widget.axis': is not true assertion

Tags: flutter

I am trying to add an ListView with horizontal scroll in ScrollablePositionedList but it is showing 'notification.metrics.axis == widget.axis': is not true error when swiped at max to either end.

UI is working fine its just this assertion was thrown multiple times. I just want to know what does this mean and will it cause any issue in future.

For reference I am using latest version i.e. `scrollable_positioned_list: ^0.3.8`

Here is an example to recreate the same:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:scrollable_positioned_list/scrollable_positioned_list.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData( 
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const ScrollDemo(),
    );
  }
}

class ScrollDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScrollDemo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: 10,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => index == 1
          ? SizedBox(height: 100,
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 5,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
            height: 100,
            width: 200,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
      )
          : Container(
        height: 100,
        width: 200,
        color: Colors.green,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How can I reproduce the error? I put this widget as the body of a `Scaffold`, and tried to scroll to both ends, but no errors shown

Comment: The UI is working fine, it's just there is an Failed assertion error in terminal, when horizontal list is swiped to max left or right

Comment: Where did you put this widget? What widget wraps it? Because I tried your code and put in just inside the body of a `Scaffold`, and I got no Failed assertion error.

Comment: @DhafinRayhan have edited question with full code and version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your demo code, tried to scroll both the `ScrollablePositionedList` and `ListView` to their two ends and got no assertion error messages.

The possibilities are:

1. You added this widget and did a hot reload, in such a way that the `AnimationController` is not ready for the layout (I don't know how to explain this in detail, but the fix is just to hot restart or re-run the app, just to be safe)
2. Adding the [`physics`](https://pub.dev/documentation/scrollable_positioned_list/latest/scrollable_positioned_list/ScrollablePositionedList/physics.html) property might help to get rid of the assertion error. Try to experiment with different physics: `BouncingScrollPhysics()`, `ClampingScrollPhysics()`, or any other `ScrollPhysics` that might suit for your need. Reference: [GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/107772)

Comment: Thanks, adding 'BouncingScrollPhysics()' resolved this issue